# Mac: What's the keyboard shortcut for switching between video mirroring and extended desktop screens?

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

What's the keyboard shortcut for switching between video mirroring and extended desktop screens? In Display Preference the feature is called "Turn On Mirroring" or "Mirror Displays." It took me some time to discover the keyboard shortcut for this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's <kbd>⌘</kbd> - <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> - <kbd>fn</kbd> - <kbd>1</kbd>, depending on the setting according to Chealion.

I found this on [Mac OS X keyboard shortcuts](http://appleguytom.blogspot.com/2008/05/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcuts.html). It's listed there as "Command-Function-1,"  but on my current generation (3rd generation?), unibody, MBP, <kbd>⌘</kbd> - <kbd>F1</kbd> is what works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work on my current-generation Macbook Pro.

Comment: Doesn't work on my 3-generations-ago MacBook Pro (Santa Rosa).

Comment: The discrepancy in use of Fn is because the F-keys can be configured to act as normal F-keys either with or without Fn pressed, with the other state activating the volume/brightness/etc. controls also printed on the keys.

Comment: **Does** work on my 2010 MBP

Comment: Works perfectly on my late 2013 MBP with MacOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Comment: In MacOS Ventura, it works for Macbooks but not for desktops.

Answer (score 9):

On older laptops (eg. earlier MacBooks, MacBook Pros, Powerbooks, etc.), by default it's simply <kbd>F7</kbd>. You will need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> if you have "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" checked off in the Keyboard and Mouse Preference Pane.

<kbd>⌘ - F1</kbd> is supposed to work but I've found it quite spotty in terms of whether it worked or not on desktop (eg. iMac, Mac Pro) machines.

Comment: My MBP has the keycap labelled with this.  I hadn't actually used it until just now, however.

Answer (score 1):

For an iMac, it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, depending on how you configure the use of the Fn keys on your computer. Don't know if they updated this for MacBooks as well.

Comment: Are you referring to "F" keys? (F1, F2, etc.) or rather the "function" key (Fn)? Or both? It's unclear when you refer to "the Fn keys" plural rather than the F-keys plural.

Comment: just something interesting on mine: i have a configured touch bar on mac without the fn keys. if i still press the command but press the key on where the f2 will be it still works. i am pressing cmd+FN+brightness low key.

Answer (score 1):

MacBookPro Monterrey and above:

⌘ + Fn + F1

Comment: Doesn't work for me ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I had a dead monitor on my iMac and connected it to a spare monitor then turned on Voice Over on boot up. From there used the tab and arrow keys to navigate to the System Prefs > Displays to turn on mirroring.