# Display on M1 MacBook is broken, need to set external monitor to be main monitor without opening up the MacBook

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, accessibility

The display on my M1 MacBook is broken. I have an external monitor and external keyboard but not an external mouse.

I am logged in to my computer on the external monitor but I can't really do anything without any mouse. I have looked at this

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204434

which suggests

> Choose “Apple menu > System Preferences”, then click Keyboard.

But the external keyboard I have is not an external Apple keyboard and I don't have a mouse so I don't know how I am going to get to that part of system preferences.

Of course if I could open my computer again I could use the keyboard and trackpad which all work fine, but to do that I should make the external monitor be the main monitor and not have it be affected by my opening the computer again.

So to get out of my situation, until I get monitor fixed, I would like primarily to be able to set the external monitor to be the main monitor unless it is not found at all.

Failing that I would like to be able to set up the keyboard based navigation of the mac when I only have an external non-mac keyboard.

Comment: For the shortcuts you might want to have a look on this.
https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/osxbasics/using-a-windows-keyboard-with-a-mac/1/

You can find the equivalent keyboard keys on your normal windows keyboard compared to an apple keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this in case someone else runs into the same situation, as it happens with the M1 MacBook screen open and the external monitor attached that external monitor was functioning as an extended display, so really all I needed to do was to move my cursor on the trackpad until it showed up on the extended display.

At that point I could of course open up system settings from the Apple menu at the top of the display, and choose displays, advanced settings, select the monitor that was not 'built-in' and use as: mirror to built-in retina display.

Silly that I didn't think of it before.

---

**EDIT**: Actually turns out that this is not dependable, I have a smaller external monitor (portable Asus ZenScreen), doesn't work with it, my giant external monitor at work it did work with (so my natural assumption is screen size has something to do with it)

**SECOND EDIT**: So this is how I made it work on my external Asus ZenScreen, basically whenever I plugged it in it never showed any menu, so I got a usb-c multi port hub. This hub I used to connect a USB-A external keyboard and a USB-A external mouse, lucky my daughter has a gaming computer, I tried with an USB-C external keyboard but it didn't do anything.

The Asus had to be connected directly to the MacBook. So when I closed the MacBook I could log in using the external keyboard, but then it turns out that when you go to Displays in Settings it doesn't give you the opportunity to mirror if there is only one display you need two displays to ask you if you want to mirror. But if I opened the MacBook again I was no longer showing the display settings where I could tell it to mirror because of having two monitors now detected, but I did have the System preferences menu on my external screen, it however did not work to make system preferences open up in that screen. I could make a folder on that screen and open it with finder and navigate to applications and open system preferences.app but it still did not open up a screen on the external monitor. I personally propose a slogan - Apple, it just doesn't work.

At any rate I found if I closed the MacBook then, when the main display was on my external monitor (without ability to set it to mirror) I could grab the displays settings window and drag it to where it was nearly off the screen and keep it selected with the mouse, then when I opened the MacBook I still had it selected and dragging it to the right where my external display was I was able pull the display window onto my external monitor. Then when I opened the MacBook again it was still over on the secondary monitor with the ability suddenly to decide how I wanted the multiple monitors to work so I set it to mirror, then I could open the MacBook again and it was mirrored.

Comment: Pressing the Command + F1 might help as well to switch between Extending your Screen and Mirroring / Duplication. If this works then credit goes to: Eugene Yokota 
https://superuser.com/questions/6988/mac-whats-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-between-video-mirroring-and-exte

Comment: @VarmintLP Hmm, no the command + F1 doesn't work, at least not on my small Asus ZenScreen monitor, I assume what happens is that it opens the screen switching dialog inside the primary monitor. It would be nice if there was just a key combination or something to tell Apple to do extend and duplicate across all monitors, or failing that telling them that the main monitor was not working. I mean monitors can be broken in the middle of tasks and it would be nice if you can hack your way to a solution.

Comment: That's what it was supposed to do. To switch between those two. Did you read the topic from the link? Maybe there are additional shortcuts to try.

Comment: I went through all of them, there was one at the end that said they used voice over on boot but didn't give many details, at any rate all of the different shortcuts did not work with my external Asus monitor and macbook pro M1